# win10 d3d9.dll hooking has not pattern 'C7 06 ?? ?? ?? ?? 89 86'

Tags: directx, hook

Hi i'm trying to hook direct x 9. (hooking dll)
The creator of the game is me, and the game has no protection.

I found the pattern "C7 06 ?? ?? ?? ?? 89 86 ?? ?? ?? ?? 89 86" which called virtual table(vtable) address.

But there has no pattern in my d3d9.dll.. 
(findpattern() function does not work and cheat engine can not find the pattern)
So i downloaded a new d3d9.dll in other website and finally i can find the pattern of vtable...

But Unfortunately i'm using Windows 10 , which can not replace d3d9.dll
(maybe win10 was based on direct x with all apps and it always said "d3d9.dll"
is used by app "xxxx.exe" )

How should i gonna do? why the win10 d3d9.dll has no byte pattern
 "C7 06 ?? ?? ?? ?? 89 86 ?? ?? ?? ?? 89 86" ??

Comment: DirectX is part of the OS, and there's no reason to believe that a specific ``d3d9.dll`` for one version of the OS is going to be bit-identical with any other version. If you are the creator of the game, what happened to your source code?

Comment: The only 'contract' for what the ``d3d9.dll`` will be from OS to OS is the public exports (functions like ``Direct3DCreate9``) and the Direct3D 9 interfaces themselves. Nothing in the binary has to be the same and in modern versions of the OS most of it is 'lofted' to newer DIrect3D versions. Replacing the ``d3d9.dll`` system DLL is just not a workable way to 'hook' any binary except locally on your system and could easily make the OS unstable as a result.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn Thanks for commenting, but first i searched about d3d9 hook.
But there is a widespread binary pattern "C7 06 ?? ?? ?? ?? ...~~" about d3dx vtable. . 
Everyone use this pattern to find dx9's vtable, but my d3d binary pattern is not that pattern...

p.s : I have  source code but  i'm studying about reverse Eng.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn I debugged and finally i found new binary pattern of my d3d9.dll (c:/windows/system32/d3d9.dll) which can find vtable address.
It was "C7 00 ?? ?? ?? ?? 89 B0 ?? ?? ?? ?? 83 4D" 
But I have no idea that why my d3d9.dll is different with any others?
(Does win 10's d3d9.dll and win 7' d3d9.dll is different? )

Comment: As I said, there's no reason to believe ``d3d9.dll`` is the same between Windows 7 RTM, Windows 7 Service Pack 1, Windows 8.0, Windows 8.1, Windows 8.1 Update, Windows 10 (10240), Windows 10 (10586), Windows 10 (14393), Windows 10 (15093) or any future version of Windows. The approach you are taking is brittle.  ``D3DX9_43.DLL`` on the other hand is the same on every one of these platforms if it's installed because it's not part of the OS. See [Not So DirectSetup](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2010/09/08/not-so-direct-setup/)